# Get the size of ID3v2 tags for an audio file

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, id3, ffprobe, id3v2

ffmpeg is the defacto tool for getting audio information from a file/URL. But I am a bit stumped on how to get the **size of the ID3v2 tags** for the same.

Example of what information ffmpeg gives when we use ffprobe:

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'FILENAME':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:04:39.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
```

The metadata values are given but what would be the way to calculate the size of this in bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the stderr output of `ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -v debug` for a line of the form

```
id3v2 ver:4 flags:00 len:137
```

Comment: Lovely! `ffprobe -i file.mp3 -v debug 2>&1 | grep id3v2` gives this statement

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10 (and as @AmigoJack added in his comment that it worked perfectly in XP and 7 too), you could use FINDSTR to parse the ouptut on STDERR:

```
ffprobe -i "FILENAME.EXT" -v debug 2>&1 | findstr /i /b /C:"id3v2"
```

The used [FINDSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) options are:
`/i Ignores the case of the characters when searching for the string.`
`/b Matches the text pattern if it is at the beginning of a line.`
   `If you ommit /b also a private tag "id3v2_priv" with leading spaces would be found`
`/C Uses the specified text as a literal search string.`

Comment: No, FINDSTR also exists on every other Windows version.

Comment: Why making fun of my name? Why restricting your answer to Windows 10 only?

Comment: @AmigoJack If you mean FINDSTR exists "since Windows 2000 Resource Kit" with "every other Windows" then you are right. (The name misspelling was not intended, sorry.)

Comment: I mentioned Windows 10 because I use Windows 10 and know for sure that it support FINDSTR.